# Possible to repair corrupted VOB file?

Tags: ffmpeg, handbrake

Trying to encode episodes from a DVD. One episode appears to be corrupted and will not play on the disk, nor will it be accepted by Handbrake of ffmpeg.

However, by copying the VTS file, VLC will play it.

When I try to encode it with `ffmpeg` this is the result:

```
ffmpeg -i ~/Movies/VTS_18_1.VOB
ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
~/Movies/VTS_18_1.VOB: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Handbrake gives this error in the log:

```
[11:15:27] macgui: Handbrake Version: 1.3.3 (2020061300)
[11:15:27] Compile-time hardening features are enabled
[11:15:27] hb_init: starting libhb thread
[11:15:27] hb_init: starting libhb thread
[11:15:42] macgui: ScanCore scanning specifically for title: 18
[11:15:42] CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9700K CPU @ 3.60GHz
[11:15:42]  - Intel microarchitecture Kaby Lake
[11:15:42]  - logical processor count: 8
[11:15:42] hb_scan: path=~/Movies/D3, title_index=18
disc.c:424: error opening file BDMV/index.bdmv
disc.c:424: error opening file BDMV/BACKUP/index.bdmv
bluray.c:2585: nav_get_title_list(~/Movies/D3/) failed
[11:15:42] bd: not a bd - trying as a stream/file instead
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 6.0.1
libdvdread: Encrypted DVD support unavailable.
libdvdread: Couldn't find device name.
libdvdnav: Can't read name block. Probably not a DVD-ROM device.
libdvdnav: vm: dvd_read_name failed
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Encrypted DVD support unavailable.
libdvdread: Couldn't find device name.
[11:15:42] scan: DVD has 27 title(s)
[11:15:42] scan: scanning title 18
[11:15:42] scan: duration is 00:05:01 (301760 ms)
[11:15:42] pgc_id: 1, pgn: 1: pgc: 0x7fa264b5b1f0
[11:15:42] scan: checking audio 1
[11:15:42] scan: id=0x80bd, lang=Unknown (AC3), 3cc=und ext=0
[11:15:42] scan: checking subtitle 1
[11:15:42] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Deutsch (4:3) [VOBSUB], 3cc=deu ext=0
[11:15:42] scan: title 18 has 1 chapters
[11:15:42] scan: chap 1, 301760 ms
[11:15:42] scan: aspect = 4:3
[11:15:42] scan: decoding previews for title 18
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
error: dvd: dvdnav_*_play failed - 
[11:15:42] scan: title angle(s) 1
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
error: dvd: dvdnav_sector_search failed - Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] scan: Too few previews (0), trying harder
[11:15:42] scan: decoding previews for title 18
[11:15:42] scan: title angle(s) 1
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] dvdnav cur pgcn err: Bad VM state.
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
libdvdread: Invalid IFO for title 18 (VTS_18_0.IFO).
libdvdnav: ifoOpenVTSI failed
[11:15:42] dvdnav prog play err: Bad VM state.
[11:15:42] libhb: scan thread found 0 valid title(s)
[11:15:43] macgui: ScanCore scan done
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of issue would normally be physical media damage, but it sounds like your video stream actually has corrupt data in it, stopping you reading the complete file - you've been able to copy the complete file from disc, and the contents are corrupt? Odd that whatever authored the disc allowed this, in my experience usually the authoring software would also barf if there's an issue.

Have a try with VOB2MPG (free/basic), see if you can get a useable MPG file from the source: https://www.videohelp.com/software/VOB2MPG

Next I'd try CloneDVD, https://www.elby.ch/en/products/clonedvd.html, see if that can extract the title. You could also try your luck with DVD Shrink, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD_Shrink, which also has some re-authoring and extraction options, just make sure to avoid the later scam versions.

If you want to try working on the file you've already extracted directly, try TMPGEnc Smart Renderer, https://tmpgenc.pegasys-inc.com/en/product/tmsr5.html. If VLC can play it, most likely Smart Renderer can repair/re-encode whatever is corrupt in the file, or worst case allow you to cut out the damaged piece. Note that VLC will play pretty much anything, it is just skipping over any corruption - the encoding tools won't do that. It's commercial, but the demo version should be sufficient.

You can also try reading the disc on different hardware, although that's usually a tactic for a physically damaged disc. Different drives will handle damage differently for various reasons, I've had scenarios where damaged discs with unreadable portions on one drive were able to be recovered on different hardware.

Hopefully at least one of these suggestions help - they're all tactics I've used, that have worked at one time or another in recovering from damaged files and media. Although this one does sound like an encoding issue in the source file, in which case a full recovery of the complete source video may not be possible.